# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c, sqlite

I am trying to connect sqlite database in c.I can see the installation of sqlite on my machine. Using

OS: Mac OS
IDE: CLION

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int connect_database();

int main() {
    printf("hello");
    connect_database();
    return 0;
}

int connect_database() {
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc;

    rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    printf("%d", rc);
    return 1;
}
```

Here is the log i got:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      _connect_database in main.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [database] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/database.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/database.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [database] Error 2
```

Comment: Show your CMake build scripts. You're probably missing telling the linker to link against sqlite.

Comment: Show your build steps. Show us which documentation you're following.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I am following this link. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link the sqlite as:

`gcc main.c -l sqlite3`

That command will generate a file named **a.out** .You can execute that file as:

`./a.out`